# Lavalink - Something broke when playing the track

Tags: lavaplayer

When I'm trying to play a song using Lavalink i get this error :

```
com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.FriendlyException: Something broke when playing the track.
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.ExceptionTools.wrapUnfriendlyExceptions(ExceptionTools.java:43) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:103) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:349) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3129) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[na:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeTrackFormat.getUrl(YoutubeTrackFormat.java:66) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeSignatureCipherManager.resolveFormatUrl(YoutubeSignatureCipherManager.java:97) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.loadBestFormatWithUrl(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:87) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:42) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:91) ~[lavaplayer-1.3.38.jar!/:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
```

I do not know what the error is and I have tried using Windows and Linux and I still get the same error.

```
[32m       .  [31m _                  _ _       _    [32m__ _ _
[32m      /\\ [31m| | __ ___   ____ _| (_)_ __ | | __[32m\ \ \ \
[32m     ( ( )[31m| |/ _` \ \ / / _` | | | '_ \| |/ /[32m \ \ \ \
[32m      \\/ [31m| | (_| |\ V / (_| | | | | | |   < [32m  ) ) ) )
[32m       '  [31m|_|\__,_| \_/ \__,_|_|_|_| |_|_|\_\[32m / / / /
[0m    =========================================[32m/_/_/_/[0m

        Version:        3.3.1
        Build:          997
        Build time:     25.03.2020 12:30:43 UTC
        Branch          master
        Commit:         29f68ba
        Commit time:    25.03.2020 12:28:48 UTC
        JVM:            14.0.1
        Lavaplayer      1.3.38
```

Comment: You are using an old version of lavalink, this has been fixed in a recent build.

Comment: I'm using verison 3.3.1 which I found [here](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink/releases). It appears to be the latest version.

Comment: That is the latest *stable* release but you can get newer dev releases from [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/fredboat/lavalink/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've downloaded the dev version and it works now, thanks again!